# Angular Universal - lazy load issue

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, universal, lazy-loading

I'm using Angular2 Universal as a starter for my project. When I setup the starter and run the app, the lazy loaded "bundle" gets loaded even though I haven't navigated to the lazy page.

[image]

Is that how it's suppose to work?

Comment: as i understand .. (but not sure) .. with Universal it server the first boot from Server .. but the files are also downloaded from the client where it re-hydrate the view after bootstraping .. so maybe this is why ..and also are you sure it is lazy loaded?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. The chunks were getting "PRELOADED" that's why it's showing in the network request.

To prevent preloading, go into browser.module.ts and remove "preloadingStrategy: IdlePreload"

Comment: I can't find preloadingStrategy: IdlePreload, what version your Angular universal is?

Comment: It is v2.1.0-rc.1